# Node Red - Count true state of Nodes

Tags: arrays, variables, global

how I can count true state of nodes?
I tried to enter the values on a array  aaa[msg_id] = true/false but I can't use global array variable.

This is my actual wrong code

```
var totale = global.get("numero_luci");

var messaggio_stato = msg.status.text;
var messaggio_id = msg._msgid;

totale.[messaggio_id] = msg.status.text;

global.set("numero_luci", totale);

msg.payload = Object.keys(totale).length;

return msg;
```

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWPyo.png)

Thanks